# JS statement separator with commas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the following js sample and am confused by the syntax.  Notice the statements are separated by commas instead of semicolons.  Are commas a valid statement separator in js?  I have not seen this before.

```
    $('selector').each(function () {

            this.onclick = function () {
                this.select();
            },

            this.onblur = function () {
            },

            this.onfocus = function () {
            },

            this.onkeyup = function () {
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Commas act as a separator between expressions in a single expression statement.  Thus, that (if it had been completed instead of being cut off after the "onkeyup" function) is just a single expression statement.

There's really no reason to code like that, or no really good reason at least.  In this particular case it has essentially the same effect as would a series of separate expression statements separated by semicolons.

The comma "operator" is questionable in many cases but useful sometimes:

```
var index, len;
for (index = 0, len = list.length; index < len; ++index) { ... }
```

for example. It allows one to drop more than one expression (assignments usually) into a grammatical locale that allows just one expression. It's really a sign of syntactic weakness, in my opinion.

Comment: Note: If anybody is interested in comma operators - see [this](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/).

Comment: @dzejkej Great site for learning JS nuances!  The style reminds me of the old C Primer and C++ Primer Plus books back in the day.

Comment: also this is interesting `for (var i = 0, ii = ary.length, a = ary[i]; i < ii; ++i, a = ary[i])` note the assignment in the final-expression statement

Comment: i just found a reason to code like this: `for()exp1,exp2;` is shorter than `for(){exp1;exp2}` I found it in a minified JS

Comment: @aldo.roman.nurena yes that saves a couple of characters. I'd be afraid to code like that (by hand) because I'd be very worried I'd forget what I was doing later :)  Of course it's a fine thing for a minifier to do.

Comment: The commas used in your example are actually not operators: they're part of the `var` statement, not of an expression. An example of comma operators in a `for` loop could be as follows: `var i = 1, j = 1; for (; i < 10; i++, j *= 2) {}`

Comment: Yes you're right; if the `var` keyword weren't there then it'd be more accurate.

Answer (score 11):

Each assignment is actually an expression (not a statement); and expressions can be concatenated into a larger expression, whose ultimate value is simply the value of the last sub-expression; e.g.

```
alert(  (w=1+1, x=2+3, y=3+3, z=4+4)  ); // shows 8
```

Although the code you showed is valid, I don't think it is a good pattern to follow. I would change it to semicolons.